# saveAsBigQueryTable doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, spotify, google-cloud-dataproc

I tried using spotify's `spark-bigquery` [spark package](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery)  to save dataframe into Google BigQuery table, but failed. I used it on Google's dataproc platform.

```
df.saveAsBigQueryTable("my-project:my_dataset.my_table")
```

here is the error log:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:215)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
>    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:438)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:474)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
>    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
>    at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameWriter$$anonfun$avro$1.apply(package.scala:26)
>    at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameWriter$$anonfun$avro$1.apply(package.scala:26)
>    at com.spotify.spark.bigquery.BigQueryDataFrame.saveAsBigQueryTable(BigQueryDataFrame.scala:54)
>    at com.spotify.spark.bigquery.BigQueryDataFrame.saveAsBigQueryTable(BigQueryDataFrame.scala:67)
>    ... 84 elided
>
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 107.0 failed 4 times
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)"
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)"
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)"
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)"
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)"
>     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)"
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)"
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)"
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
>   Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.getFileExtension(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:299)"
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)"
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)"
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)"
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)"
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)"
>     ... 8 more"
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
>    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
>    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
>    ... 121 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
>    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scal
>   a:335)
>    ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.getFileExtension(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:299)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
>    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
>    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
>    ... 8 more

Comment: What are the versions you are using for spark-bigquery and the image version for Dataproc?

Comment: for spark-bigquery: `com.spotify:spark-bigquery_2.11:0.2.1`. I didn't specify image version in launching Dataproc, but I looked at the detail of the cluster, it is `1.2.14`.

Comment: I have tried other Dataproc versions as well, it looks like all 1.2. versions don't work.

Comment: any special chars in the dataset or table name, or really long names (just checking)?

Comment: no, I have run test with simple table and simple table name. You can verify that on your side easily by creating a simple df and do saveAsBigQueryTable. i wonder if that happens to you too. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The part that I find suspicious is the bit that reads: Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.getFileExtension(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Ljava/lang/String; at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:299)"

Searching for this particular error leads to: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/208.

As spark-avro has trouble with Spark 2.2, you may find using Dataproc image version [1.1](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions) (Spark 2.0) makes the spark-bigquery library function properly.